# Suppressing Lint Warnings in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, lint, text-size

My understanding is that suppressing individual warnings can be done in XML by adding an `ignore` property, e.g.

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="SpUsage"
android:textSize="30dp"
```

This works fine when the text size is directly specified. But when I use a reference to a dimension, e.g.

```
android:textSize="@dimen/largeTextSize"
```

Lint produces a warning in spite of the ignore.

Let's assume that the given case is a justified exception, and that the guidance on generally preferring `sp` dimensions over `dp` for text is well understood and followed.

Because this is an exception I do not want to disable the warning globally. How can I do it locally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the suppression on the `dimen` value resource:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
     <dimen name="largeTextSize" tools:ignore="SpUsage">123dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only that approach helped me:
Specify lint checking preferences in the *lint.xml* file. Place it in the root directory of your Android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="SpUsage" severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

More about lint config look at: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#config

Comment: Noticed this as I’m checking some old stuff. This had been answered long ago. I don’t see how your solution would ignore this specific occurrence rather than suppressing the warning globally, which is not intended as explicitly stated in the question.